# Error with group by statement

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

The following query :

```
SELECT a.vendor_id, a.crew_type_id, count(a.vendor_id) as `totalVendor` 
FROM tb_vendor_crew_type_details as a
WHERE a.market = 1
  AND a.crew_available > 0 
  AND a.crew_type_id IN (161, 183, 220, 221, 227)
Group by a.vendor_id
Having totalVendor >= 5
```

throws an error:

```
SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated 
column 'scope_worker_dev.a.crew_type_id' which is not functionally 
dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with 
sql_mode=only_full_group_by 0.00037 sec
```

What could be the reason for this? What mistake am I making in my query?

Answer (score 0):

Suppose to have full group by based on your select statement

```
SELECT a.vendor_id,a.crew_type_id,count(a.vendor_id) as `totalVendor` 
FROM tb_vendor_crew_type_details as a WHERE a.market = 1  AND a.crew_available 
> 0 
AND a.crew_type_id 
IN ( 161,183,220,221,227)  Group by a.vendor_id, a.crew_type_id Having totalVendor >=5
```

Answer (score 0):

In mysql, if sql_mode is `only_full_group_by`, it means in `select` clause, should only have columns in `group by` or other column with aggregational function.

Like your query and what you want to do, should be like this:

```
SELECT a.vendor_id, count(a.vendor_id) as `totalVendor` 
FROM tb_vendor_crew_type_details as a
WHERE a.market = 1 
AND a.crew_available > 0 
AND a.crew_type_id IN ( 161,183,220,221,227) 
Group by a.vendor_id Having totalVendor >= 5
```

Or use `group_concat` to concat `crew_type_id` in each group:

```
SELECT a.vendor_id, group_concat(a.crew_type_id) as crew_type_ids, count(a.vendor_id) as `totalVendor` 
FROM tb_vendor_crew_type_details as a
WHERE a.market = 1
AND a.crew_available > 0 
AND a.crew_type_id IN ( 161,183,220,221,227) 
Group by a.vendor_id Having totalVendor >= 5
```

If `crew_type_id` does make no sense for you and without modifing your query, you can remove `only_full_group_by` from `sql_mode`:

```
set @@global.sql_mode = replace(lower(@@global.sql_mode), 'only_full_group_by', '');
```